# Kubernetes how to limit the number of identical pitches on the node?

Tags: kubernetes

Good afternoon
Actually how to disable the start-up of 2 identical pods on the same node.
there are 2 nodes.
there is Deployment with 2 replicas
when you turn off the 2nd node on the 1st run 2 of the same hearth of the deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity. Configure podAntiAffinity with requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution to prevent scheduling two copies of the same pod on the same node.

Comment: Could you explain yourself better? I don't understand the last part. hearth?

Comment: He means he doesn't want to run two pods of the same type on a given node. The official example uses Redis. There should only be one instance of Redis running per node (at most), so you set anti-affinity to disable scheduling a Redis pod to a node where one is already running.